# Cannot get input to stay on same line as inline-block div element

Tags: jquery, html

I can't understand why this is happening: I have two inline `div` elements (one with a submit button inside) that are normally side-by-side. I then want to make the second `div` invisible (`display: none;`) and then implement the `slideToggle` jQuery function to show/hide the button.

When the second `div` is initially visible, they are side-by-side and everything works fine. But when it is initially invisible, upon clicking the `div` to show the button, it appears underneath the first `div`.

JSFiddle: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zec4S/))

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:500px; background:red;" onclick="$('#button_div').slideToggle('fast');">
        <h2 style="display:inline-block;">Some text</h2>
    </div>


    <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; display: none;" id="button_div" name="button_div">
       <input type="submit" id="create_button" name="create_button" value="Create" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare `display: inline-block;` through non inline css to your element then jQuery will toggle between `inline-block` and `none` rather than `block`:

**CSS**

```
#button_div {
    display:inline-block;
}​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zec4S/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should to use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`, or `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none;`.

Comment: Afaik it's called initialism in English. Lern about it more

Comment: We usually call it lazy or illiterate around here. It's not a text message, dude. Quality matters.